# How to change MATLAB path to compile mex files of FLANN with cmake command?

Tags: matlab, compilation, makefile, cmake, flann

I try to compile FLANN on a remote machine which I am not a root user. For this purpose I compiled cmake at my home and set an alias to call. I also downloaded FLANN from web and process the compilation as it is suggested at the manual.

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

It is compiled without an error but the matlab module and mex compilation. Even I add the matlab bin into $PATH it gives following warning after `cmake ..`.

```
...
CMake Warning at src/matlab/CMakeLists.txt:57 (message):
  The 'mex' and 'mexext' programs have been found in different locations.
  It's likely that one of them is not part of the MATLAB instalation.  Make
  sure that the 'bin' directory from the MATLAB instalation is in PATH
...
```

Because of this issue, matlab mex files are not compiled when I execute `make`. 
I could not solve this problem in any way even I tried to set some cmake configurations. Is there any suggestion to deal with this compilation problem?

```
echo $PATH
/home/y/bin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/matlab/bin

which mex
/usr/local/bin/mex

which mexext
/usr/local/matlab/bin/mexext
```

Comment: Could you add the output of these three commands: `echo $PATH`, `which mex`, and `which mexext`?

Comment: I solve the problem by taking the matlab path to first place on $PATH

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution (that worked for me) is to create a symbolic link for **mexext** in */usr/local/bin* that points to where **mexext** is actually found.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/mexext /usr/local/bin/mexext
```

Answer (score 2):

(The solution is in the comments. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> I solved the problem by taking the matlab path to first place on `$PATH`